# FFmpeg: How to open a file with an apostrophe in its name?

Tags: ffmpeg, io, escaping, filenames

I am trying to concatenate a bunch of audio files with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i Filelist.txt -c copy out.mp3
```

Unfortunately, one of my audio files has an apostrophe in its name, which are used to indicate the start and end of the filename:

```
file 'Murfy's in Trouble!.mp3'
```

giving the following error:

```
                            Impossible to open 'Murfy%s'
Filelist.txt: No such file or directory
```

I tried escaping it with `\` and `%`, but those don't work. Is there any way around this without changing all my filenames?

Comment: What is your OS/shell/language?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10, and I call from Python 3.7 using `subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-f', 'concat', '-safe', '0', '-i', "Filelist.txt", "-c", "copy", os.path.basename(os.getcwd()) + ".mp3"], shell=True, cwd=os.getcwd())`.

Answer (score 3):

Escaping `'` in a quote needs to be done with `'\''`, as per [the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#toc-Examples).